# Why doesn't a neutral zone infraction stop play?

Tags: american-football

Why is it that a false start by the offense stops play but neutral zone infraction by defense does not?

I understand why holding penalties don't stop play because the play is ongoing and they don't want players to get injured, but with a neutral zone infraction the play is at the same step as a false start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is when the penalty occurs.

A false start by the offense, or certain penalties by the defense (illegally forcing an offensive player to move) are dead-ball fouls.  They occur prior to the snap of the ball.  As there is no play, the penalty must be enforced prior to the snap.

A defensive player offside is not a penalty until the ball is actually snapped and the play begins.  A defensive player could return to a legal position prior to the snap.  This is not a dead-ball foul, so the play continues.